# How to remove GNOME 3.10 and all extensions from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome, uninstall

I guess the issue is already explained in the title.I want to remove GNOME 3.10 SHELL and all installed extensions in order to get clean ubuntu 14.04 but with all my software and private files saved. I've tried some commands found on the internet but i keep getting errors. What is the easiest way? For example to uninstall it in one or to terminal commands?

Answer (score 0):

I have found something like this:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell-*
```

It worked. Can you please tell me if I should do anything else to remove something that might have stayed installed somewhere deep inside the system

Answer (score 0):

to remove all extension run it:

```
rm -rf  ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/*
sudo rm -rf  /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/*
```

to uninstall gnome-shell run this:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

if they give you errors, show us.

Comment: It gave me no errors but I've used the command which I posed above. Thanks for help anyway :)